# Can I remove this "SSD Partition" from my hard disk storage?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

My disk partitions are like this:

[image]

C is an SSD with the OS. D is an SSD with my User files on it, and H is a HHD for all other files that is, storage.

C is the boot drive, installed a fresh copy of Win7 on it last week. H is a drive that is about 2 years old that I have put into this computer to use, and today is when I first noticed the "SSD Reserved" partition on it. I am not sure where or how it got there, although that drive is not used as a boot driver. So is it safe to delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not seen a partition named `SSD Reserved` before, and I'd be surprised if it were required for booting. Normally a 100MB 'System Reserved' partition could be made, which is detailed [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg441289.aspx)

> This “stub” of a partition, which is new in Windows 7, serves two
>   functions. First, it holds the Boot Manager code and the Boot
>   Configuration Database. Second, it reserves space for the startup
>   files required by the BitLocker Drive Encryption feature. If you ever
>   decide to encrypt your system drive using BitLocker, you won’t have to
>   repartition your system drive to make it possible.

As I'm not sure if this is that partition or not, as it would usually be labelled differently, you could do two things:

1. Check the contents of the partition by `Right click`ing on the partition, and clicking `Change Drive Letter and Paths`. Add an unused drive letter and browse the contents, it should be quite easy to search for any files you found and see if they're related to a system reserved partition.
2. Disconnect the drive from your machine and see if the machine has any trouble booting. Test it and if you have no issues, it's safe to assume it's not going to cause any harm removing the one partition.

In all honesty, it's such a small amount of space it probably isn't worth the hassle to remove it and then resize the large partition to fill the space (You can't resize to the left of the partition as easily as to the right, the contents will need to be shifted left and then the expansion made after the partition). Personally, I'd leave it be, it's doing no harm.

Comment: I think you are right, it is wise just to leave it then, especially at the risk and only saving 100MB. It's mainly that I just wanted to clear the disks up, it's just slightly irritating that the disks are messy. I hadn't thought about unplugging this drive and trying to boot with it so thank you for that.

Answer (score 4):

The **System Reserved Partition** (Called **SSD Reserved** in your case) holds the Boot Configuration Database, Boot Manager Code, Windows Recovery Environment and reserves space for the startup files which may be required by BitLocker, in case you use the BitLocker Drive Encryption feature. (More on this partition see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/).)

It is created during a clean fresh installation of Windows 7, and later versions Windows OS. For Windows 7 it is 100 MB.

In hindsight, when you do your Windows 7 install make sure that there are no drives connected apart from the one you're going to install onto. If another drive is available then the install kit will put the reserved partition there instead of on the OS drive.

I would recommend that you not delete this partition. If you want to (I don't see it necessary) relocate the System Reserved partition you could unplug all drives exept the one containing the OS, and then follow the instructions here to recreate the System Reserved partition via running startup repairs: [Windows 7: Startup Repair - Run 3 Separate Times](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/105541-startup-repair-run-3-separate-times.html?ltr=S)

Comment: Haven't seen System Reserved labelled as SSD Reserved, maybe I haven't used SSDs :p

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Any idea on how it ended up on this H drive instead of C?

Comment: As I wrote, when installing Windows only the drive where you're installing it should be plugged in. If not the System Reserved partition can sometimes find its way onto a different drive than the OS one.

Answer (score 0):

Given it's only 0.1 GB in size, I wouldn't worry about it.  The space you'd recover wouldn't be worth the risk that Windows is using it in some way you don't know about.

Comment: I understand, it is wise to leave it since it's 100MB but I just want it all to be  clean.. :p